# For a perfect group $G$, does taking universal perfect central extensions stabilize?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a perfect group (finite, if necessary). Let
$$1\rightarrow K\rightarrow E\rightarrow G\rightarrow 1$$
be a universal perfect central extension of $G$, so that $K$ is isomorphic to the Schur multiplier of $G$, and $E$ is the Schur cover of $G$, and is itself a perfect group.

Is $E$ "universal" in the sense that $E$ is its own Schur cover?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, because for a perfect group $F$ one has [Grün's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_group#Gr.C3.BCn.27s_lemma) $$Z(F) = Z_{2}(F).$$

So if one considers the universal perfect central extension of $E$
$$1\rightarrow L\rightarrow F\overset{\pi}{\rightarrow}E\rightarrow 1$$
then
$$
\pi^{-1}(K) \le Z_{2}(F)
$$
(I am assuming for simplicity that $K \to E$ is inclusion)
so that $\pi^{-1}(K)$ must be central in $F$, so
$$
1\rightarrow \pi^{-1}(K)\rightarrow F\overset{\pi}{\rightarrow}G\rightarrow 1
$$
is central, etc.

Comment: @JEFFYELTON, thanks for the correction, I hadn't noticed that $\pi$ was on the wrong arrow!

Comment: Here you're assuming that $G$ is center-free?

Comment: @JEFFYELTON, sorry, one more correction. Hopefully is ok now. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so just to be pedantic, you're proving that the universal perfect central extension of a perfect group itself has no perfect central extensions.

Comment: @JEFFYELTON, yes, I believe that's it.